# What is a possible name of a course that teaches parity?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

(I know, it sounds weird). So "parity," in Maths, is the fact of being even or odd. Let's say if there was an academic course that teaches you about parity, what should be its (one-word) name? Paritiology? Paritism?

Comment: It's a cool question.  It wouldn't be **a whole course**, but you can imagine, say, a textbook chapter style using this SWR!  Good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "paritology" or "parital mathematics" would be your best options. `-ism` is out, as it's a suffix used for processes, conditions, beliefs.

The suffix `-ology` is used to denote the study of something, but I feel it connotes a larger subject of study. Most `-ologies` that come to mind refer to larger bodies of knowledge. E.g., Geology, methodology, psychology. There are some that deal with small subjects but they are still rather complex studies.

I personally think "parital mathematics" would be a better option. `-al` is a suffix meaning "relating to" and its uses are akin to the one you're seeking. It also has some specific uses in mathematics already: Tropical geometry, umbral calculus, spherical trigonometry, spectral geometry, spatial geometry. "Paritic mathematics" would also work and is a bit easier on the ears.

Limiting yourself to one word is really the determining factor. Paritology would be my choice if you *need* one word. If you can accommodate two, I would use "Parital mathematics." Since parity is really a specific subset of a much larger body of knowledge and not a system itself, I would prefer "parital" or "paritic" over "paritology."

More on the suffix [-ology](https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/-logy.html). And for more on the suffix [-al](https://www.msu.edu/~defores1/gre/sufx/gre_suffx.htm)

Comment: "Parital math" or perhaps "paritals" is amazing!